# Core Data Installation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am using core data to save data from web services in my app. On the first time of running, app creates the core data instance and attributes and properties and save all the data. My question is that, when the application runs second time or many times, Is the core data creates its instance and properties and save all data again, or again and again? I am sorry if my question is not relevant.

Thanks

Comment: Data duplicacy may occur. Did you tried outputting the data?

Comment: I am not facing any problem regarding this issue, i am just asking that whenever the app runs, it creates Core data from start? or just append the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Webservice + code for storing data to coredata gets called every time you run app, core data will store objects again and again

You can solve this by 2 ways

1. If your data from server remains the same, you can set a flag and check that coredata insertion should execute only once
2. If you data from server may keep on changing, you can Update data instead of inserting it again to avoid duplicate records.

Comment: My data is keep changing, so it means whenever the app runs, it creates core data from start and again inserts the data?

Comment: Yes, if you dont update records and insert them everytime, coredata will add same records to table again and again

Answer (score 0):

If u want to make sure the data is unique, u should make sure the data object should have a unique key.
For example:

```
@interface Person : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * pid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@end
```

The property of Person.pid should be unique. It means that u can only get one person max with the appointed pid.

So before u insert new object, u should query the db with NSFetchRequest(NSPredicate) like this:

```
NSNumber *aimPid;// the person's pid
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pid == %@", aimPid]];
```

If person exist, then just update and save.

If person not exist, then insert a new one and save.

More:https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/